Workaround for using DetachedCriteria with JPA & Hibernate-6?
In my org, many applications heavily depend on the DetachedCriteria of Hibernate.
The application sends DetachedCriteria to the library which internally uses hibernate sessions and sends the result back. The library acts as a good abstraction for hibernate.
I want to upgrade this library to hibernate-6 & JPA(Jakarta). But DetachedCriteria is deprecated in this latest version.
Is there any workaround for using DetachedCriteria (or something similar) to do the same?
